# Comparing slopes between different regression lines in the same sample

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I have two models:

`mod1 <- glm(y ~ A + CONTROL1 + CONTROL2, data = dat,family=binomial(link="logit"))`
`mod2 <- glm(y ~ B + CONTROL1 + CONTROL2, data = dat,family=binomial(link="logit"))`

I'm trying to determine if slope A in mod1 is significantly different from slope B in mod2.

I'll give a reproducible example here:

`mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")`
`mydata$sat<-rnorm(400, mean=1350, sd=100) # randomly generate SAT scores`
`m1 <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")`
`m2 <- glm(admit ~ sat + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")`

I am interested in finding out if the slope associated with `gre` in m1 is significantly different from the slope associated with `sat` in m2.

What are some tests in R that can help me get there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252325/is-there-a-statisical-method-for-comparing-slopes-of-logistic-regressions.  Especially the first comment and the corresponding link.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a duplicate. The questions in the two threads are quite a bit different. I'm not asking about how slopes might vary by subgroups.

Comment: That's why I indicated they are possible -- admittedly they may not apply -- I just scanned them because I remember a similar question before.  I guess one question I'd have is why are you fitting separate models?  Can you update the question a bit to tell us why you are doing separate models as opposed to fitting a single model with an interaction term?

Comment: Thanks for your follow up. I'm not fitting a single model with an interaction term because there's no theoretical reason for doing so. In the example, there's no reason to think that the effect of "gre" on the likelihood of admittance varies by "sat" scores. I'm only trying to see if there's a different effect between "gre" and "sat" on the outcome variable. m1 and m2 aren't nested models.

Comment: Have you tested that theory?  Couldn't you just include gre and sat in the same model and test contrasts?  It seems you'd want to account for both of these since both influence admission.  I'm not sure you can have one without the other in any admission process that I know of.

Comment: the test scores are generally highly correlated. I don't want to include them in the same model due to multicollinearity. Anyways, I simply want to see if the slope associated with "gre" is different from the one associated with "sat".

Comment: OK. Can you tell us what the end goal of your analysis is?  Is it to obtain the best prediction possible or is it only to determine if gre or sat is a better predictor, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the end goal simply is to determine is "gre" or "sat" is a better predictor

Comment: See: Comparing Coefficients of Nonlinear Multivariate Regression Models Between Equations Survey Research Methods. 2015;9(3):159-167 DOI 10.18148/srm/2015.v9i3.6211.  You might also consider computing standardized coefficients for comparison purposes.  In addition, I think you are better off creating some sort of a composite function of gre and sat (think PCA scores) since, in real world admissions processes, admission staff don't have one or the other.

Comment: Also, another helpful CV link:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8718/comparing-logistic-regression-coefficients-across-models

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments that your goal is to determine if GRE or SAT does better at predicting.  Given that this is your goal, and that all other variables in your model appear to be identical, I'd suggest the following approach.

Simply test your `GRE` model on a hold-out sample of data and compute the mean squared predicted error (MSPE).  Do the same thing with the `SAT` model.  Then, select the model that has the lowest mean squared predicted error as this model does the best job of predicting.  You could even perform cross-validation or jackknife estimates with these methods and compare the averaged MSPEs.

That being said, in the real world, rarely do school admissions offices receive only a GRE or only and SAT (I believe).  As you've provided in your example, both factors likely contribute to the admission decision.  As a result, I think you are better off creating a composite index of both GRE and SAT (perhaps by using a PCA score of GRE and SAT) and placing it in your model.