# Comparing different regression lines as their slopes are equal or not

Tags: r, regression, time-series, anova, ancova

I have a 4-set of time series data and each dataset has a response and its recorded date as a decimal year. For instance, there is a dataset from 2002 to 2013 having 200 data points, each data point has recorded on a distinct decimal year. I obtained slope for each data-set as my predictor is 'decimal year'. Hence, I obtained 4 different slopes for 4 datasets and I had to plot in a different graph as all these time series datasets were recorded on a distinct decimal year. My question is how can I compare these four slopes obtained from each data set as they are statistically equal or not. I went through various methods: ANOVA, t-tests, ANCOVA etc., but never got a clear idea. I am doing this analysis in r.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your 4 responses? Are they all measured on the same scale? Are they all measured during the same time period?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/231059/11849

Comment: @IsabellaGhement The 4 responses have overlapping recording periods not exactly the same time period for example one response was recorded from 2002 to 2013 but another response was measured from 2011 to 2017, however, they were measured on the same scale.