# Can I use the linearHypothesis function to test whether the coefficients from two seperate linear models are equal?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing

Lets say we have two identical regression equations (linear_model_1 and linear_model_2), however both are run on independent samples of differing sizes.

Can I use the linearHypothesis function to jointly test whether the vector of coefficients from linear_model_1 are equal to linear_model_2? Or is there another function that would be more appropriate in this case?

For now, I have tested whether the coefficients for each regressor are equal independently (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions)), however I think it would be more appropriate to test this hypothesis jointly.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: you can combine the datasets and simply add a dummy variable for each source that interacts with each coefficient.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/231091/11849