Is possible to test the differente between two coefficients for different regressions at R?
I have two regressions and I need to test if there are a difference between the coefficients.

df1 = data.frame(   estimate = c(0.04854144, -0.00105855,0.00051479),
std.error = c(0.00918019, 0.00501731,0.00680725),   row.names =
c('(Intercept)', 'first', 'second') )
df2 = data.frame(   estimate = c(0.55632466, 0.03208915, -0.00066974),
std.error = c(0.07542807, 0.00231743, 0.00165630),   row.names =
c('(Intercept)', 'first', 'second') )

But I don't know how to do it and if is it possible.

This discussion might help.

If you fit these regression models yourself, combine the data and fit one model: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/231091/11849
